# Is using a mapping as argument scalable?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is a function with an argument that is a mapping scalable in terms of gas?
If too many elements are added in this mapping, would it become problematic for the protocol?

Example:

```
mapping(uint256 tokenId => uint256 amount) internal tokenInfo;

function transferSomething(mapping(uint256 => uint256) _tokenInfo) {
    contract.getBalance(_tokenInfo);
}
```

Comment: Your `transferSomething` function syntax is invalid, can you edit and correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to using a `mapping`, gas costs remain constant for the following reasons and thus it's scalable in that aspect.

##### Storage Pointers, Not Data

When passing a mapping to a function in Solidity, you're actually passing a storage pointer rather than the whole data structure. Storage pointers are constant-size variables, meaning they occupy the same space regardless of the size of the mapping they point to.

##### No Iteration Overheads

Unlike arrays, where computational complexity can increase with the array size(if the function iterates over the array), mapping operations are generally O(1) in the EVM. Whether you're adding, deleting, or fetching elements, the gas costs remain constant because you're directly accessing the storage slot via a hash of the key.